# Is there a way to filter a MongoDB document by other values within that document?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, mongo-collection

I have a document I'm trying to filter with rows created by aggregation functions that look like:

```
{
   "_id": {
      "ID": "randNum01"
   },
   "ImportantVal1": 50,
   "importantVal2": 22
}

{
   "_id": {
      "ID": "randNum02"
   },
   "ImportantVal1": 40,
   "importantVal2": 100
}

{
   "_id": {
      "ID": "randNum03"
   },
   "ImportantVal1": 60,
   "importantVal2": 2
}
```

How could I use an aggregation function to only choose the rows where importantVal1 > importantVal2?

I'm currently trying something like:

```
{
   "$match": {
      "ImportantVal1": {
         "$gt": "$importantVal2"
      }
   }
}
```

but it returns nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
{$match:{$expr:{$gt:["$ImportantVal1", "$ImportantVal2"]}}}
```

Check out [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) for more information.